# How to Display a value in a field on Partner Tech CD7220-UN Customer Display using java script or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you suggest me how to display a value in a field on Partner Tech CD7220-UN USB Customer Display using java script or jquery ? (the ystem is run on Firefox)

Comment: Do you know if it supports JavaScript and if so, is jQuery loaded into the display? You need to give us something....

Comment: I think it supports java script, I tried this code and I it didn't work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033585/clear-pole-display-text-using-chrome-serial

Comment: I think that then you number one priority is to look up if the display supports JavaScript.